# I do not want duplicate items to be rendered and to show in item_number how many duplicate items there are but the map does not do this

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, developer-tools

{arrOfProducts.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      
    );
  }, 0)}
;

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? How you tried to debug what's wrong?

Comment: I do not want duplicate items to be rendered and to show in item_number how many duplicate items there are but the map does not do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays has method `reduce`

```
arrOfProducts.reduce((acc, curr) => {
const foundedIndex = acc.findIndex(i => curr.id === i.id)
if(foundedIndex !== -1){
    const item = acc[foundedIndex]
    return [...acc.slice(0, foundedIndex), {...item, count: item.count+1}, ...acc.slice(foundedIndex+1)]
}
return [...acc, {...curr, count: 1}]
}, [])
```